# При добавлении HTML кода с помощью .prepend()|jQuery никакие события на добавленный код не срабатывают

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
if(incorrectURLs) {
$('#for_errors').prepend('' +
    '<div class="message message--warning">'+icon+'' +
        '<div class="message-body">' +
             '<p class="message-text">' +
                 'Внимание!...' +
             '</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="message-close"></div></div>'
    );
    return false;
}

$('.message-close').on('click', function() {
    console.log('sdsd');
    $(this).closest('.message').hide();
});
```

в таком виде в логах ничего не происходит.
Но если вставить тот же HTML код в дом дерево вручную, срабатывает без проблем.
Почему не срабатывает при добавлении с помощью jQuery и как это решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменить

```
$('.message-close').on('click', function() {
```

на

```
$(document).on('click', '.message-close', function() {
```

---

Не срабатывает потому. что слушатель вешается **ДО** того, как элемент появится на странице. Надо вешать слушателя либо сразу после добавления, либо **[делегировать](https://webref.ru/dev/jqfundamentals/events)** событие элементу, который всегда на странице есть. В текущем примере это `document`

Comment: Давно хотел спросить, а есть какой-то список событий, который всплывают при делегировании? Например с событием `input` так не прокатит же.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events